# Perfect Number between 1 and 1000

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

I try to find the perfect number between 1 and 1000, i wrote this code but it didn't work!
what is wrong?

```
public class Perfect {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int sum=0;
        for (int n = 1; n < 1000; n++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n/2 ; j++) {
                if (n % j == 0)
                    sum = sum + j;
            }
            if (sum == n) {
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: You never reset the value of `sum`, so at each iteration it starts with its previous value.

Comment: from the start your condition `j < n/2` will not be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the *declaration* (and more importantly the *initialization*) of `sum` ***into*** the `for` loop. Also, you need to test `<=` in the inner loop. Something like,

```
for (int n = 1; n < 1000; n++) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int j = 1; j <= n / 2; j++) {
```

And I get `496`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Actually, you get 6, 28 AND 496.